# Foreign Keys on two different schemas mysql

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have two tables on distinct schemas

1. db1.invoice

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db1.`invoice` (
>   `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `qsales_sale_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `invoice_id_from_dosage_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `enterprise_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `subsidiary_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `subsidiary_address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `subsidiary_phone` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `client_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `nit` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `was_paid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`),
>   KEY `fk_invoice_qsales_sale1_idx` (`qsales_sale_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=457 ;
> ```

2. bd2.qsale_sale

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db2.qsales_sale (
>   `qsales_sale_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `qsales_order_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `total_cost` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `currency` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>   `has_discount` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `is_wholesaler` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `payment_type` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`qsales_sale_id`),
>   KEY `fk_qsales_sale_qsales_order_type1_idx` (`qsales_order_type_id`),
>   KEY `fk_qsales_sale_client1_idx` (`client_id`),
>   KEY `fk_qsales_sale_employee1_idx` (`created_by`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=51 ;
> ```

then i want to add a foreign key
I try:
1.

```
alter table bd1.invoice
 add foreign key fk_invoice_qsales_sale1(qsales_sale_id) 
     references db2.qsales_sale (qsales_sale_id)
     on delete cascade
     on update cascade;
```

2. ALTER TABLE db1.invoice
     ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_invoice_qsales_sale1` FOREIGN KEY (`qsales_sale_id`) 
   REFERENCES `db2`.`qsales_sale` (`qsales_sale_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

But i have this error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`qfix`.`#sql-a28_5`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-a28_5_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`qsales_sale_id`) REFERENCES `qsales`.`qsales_sale` (`qsales_sale_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

0.625 sec
```

Comment: in 1st table "qsales_sale_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL," but in second table "qsales_sale_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"

Comment: You are adding or updating data that fails the constraint

Comment: So to me it is not a case of "I am trying to add a constraint" that failed. It is that you are in data insert or update mode that you get the error. So re-check what you think you are doing.

Comment: Ooops correction, my bad. The problem is that your existing data does not support the FK that you want to put in place.